# SuiteCRM: Problem with PDF templates (failed to open stream)

Tags: php, suitecrm, synology

I installed SuiteCRM 7.11.19, Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344) on my Synology NAS. So far, everything works fine, except creating PDF templates. When I go to PDF - Templates and click Create, I get the following error:

> Warning:
> require_once(/volume1/web/suitecrm7/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/samples/@eaDir):
> failed to open stream: Success in
> /volume1/web/suitecrm7/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/views/view.edit.php
> on line 47 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> ‘modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/samples/@eaDir’
> (include_path=’/volume1/web/suitecrm7:/volume1/web/suitecrm7/include/…:.:/usr/share/pear’)
> in
> /volume1/web/suitecrm7/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/views/view.edit.php
> on line 47

I’ve given the user group http the following rights:

- on folder *web*: full read
- on folder */web/suitecrm7/modules*: full read and write
- on folder */web/suitecrm7/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/samples*: full control

I’m missing something, but I have no idea what. Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sabrina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be something wrong with your permissions on the sample files. I suggest you double check these.

Note that the easiest solution, if you don't need the samples however, is to remove the files in *modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/samples* (maybe take a back-up just in case).